# Where is the log for ACPI events?

Tags: linux-mint, logs, suspend, acpi

Running Mint 14. Sometimes I can suspend fine, but after my computer is on for a while, it no longer suspends. It wakes up after a second or so without any external inputs.

My guess is that I'm monitoring something I don't need to monitor:

```
>cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
LID       S4    *enabled   
SLPB      S3    *enabled   
IGBE      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:19.0
EXP3      S4    *disabled  
XHCI      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
EHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
HDEF      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
```

These devices are rather cryptic. Although it might be interesting to know what the devices are, all I really care about is the one that is causing my computer to wake up (so I can disable monitoring of that device). Is there a log file somewhere that keeps track of ACPI events that would tell me which device woke up my computer?

Answer (score 2):

All the log record during the ACPI events will be recorded at

```
 /var/log/acpid.log
```

Open your terminal and type as

```
tail -f /var/log/acpi.log
```

that will lists you content of ACPI log file.

hope that helps.

Comment: I don't have acpi.log. I checked syslog, which shows that ACPI changed power states on several devices, then the CPUs went offline, then I got "Extended CMOS year:2000" (not sure if that is pre- or post- resume), then the next message is "ACPI: Low-level resume complete". So there isn't much syslogging of the actual resume process. Why is there no acpi.log?

Comment: Some searches turned up apcid.log, which is not in /var/log.

Comment: *bump* in the night

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `sudo acpi_listen`

It is in the package `acpid`, which you may want to remove after debugging. I'm not sure if Mint uses it/needs it, and it may interfere with other power saving systems, e.g. in `systemd`.

`acpitool -e` is also useful, you can see the things that may cause events.

Answer (score 0):

Some acpi events seem to be here (linux mint 18 sarah)

```
 grep -i acpi /var/log/kern.log |head
```